# Using Find.BySelector with the :visible filter in WatiN throws error

Tags: watin

I am using WatiN 2.1 to drive Internet Explorer for automated integration testing.  For one of my tests, I want to select an item in a dynamically created popup menu after clicking on a button that creates the menu.  The menu itself is a jQuery plug-in that creates an unordered list with a specific class.

I am using WatiN 2.0's new Find.BySelector method to search via this specific class and that works great.  However, in tests where multiple menus are created, I'm having a difficult time selecting the menu that is visible at the time.  For this, I thought I would use the :visible filter to limit my results to only those menus that are visible (only one can be visible at a time). However, when I use the following code:

```
WebBrowser.Current.ElementOfType<List>(Find.BySelector("li.fg-menu:visible"));
```

I get a WatiN.Core.Exceptions.RunScriptException thrown with the message: "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101"  While searching for this specific HRESULT, people have recommended running Visual Studio as an Administrator, but this does not fix the problem.  Without the :visible filter it works fine.  When I execute that selector directly in the console window of the browser (using jQuery), it returns what I want.

To fix this, I could use WatiN's built-in ability to execute my own JavaScript to return an element, but I'm wondering if anyone else has been successful at using :visible with Find.BySelector.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've gone with [this solution](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/11/11/fast-er-css-selector-based-element-lookups-in-watin-via-jquery/).  It executes the selector in JavaScript using a "real" copy of jQuery already on the page.  I've modified it a bit to dynamically insert the helper JavaScript based on whether it's already been inserted.  It is also generic so you can specify the type of Element you want returned.  Here is all the relevant extension methods for the browser object:

```
    public static bool IsJavascriptEvaluateTrue(this Browser browser, string javascript)
    {
        var evalResult = browser.Eval("if (" + javascript + ") {true;} else {false;}");
        return evalResult == "true";
    }

    public static TElementType FindViaJQuery<TElementType>(this Browser browser, string cssSelector) where TElementType : Element
    {
        if (!browser.IsJavascriptEvaluateTrue("typeof('WatinSearchHelper') == 'function'"))
        {
            var js = "WatinSearchHelper = function () { " +
                     "    var earTagId = 1; " +
                     "    var getElementId = function (cssSelector) { " +
                     "        var resultId = \"_no_element_\"; " +
                     "        var el = $(cssSelector); " +
                     "        if (el.length > 0) { " +
                     "            var firstEl = el[0]; " +
                     "            if (firstEl.id == \"\") { " +
                     "                firstEl.id = \"_watin_search_\" + earTagId++; " +
                     "            } " +
                     "            resultId = firstEl.id; " +
                     "        } " +
                     "        return resultId; " +
                     "    }; " +
                     "    return { getElementId: getElementId }; " +
                     "} (); ";

            browser.Eval(js);
        }

        var elementId = browser.Eval(string.Format("WatinSearchHelper.getElementId(\"{0}\")", cssSelector));

        if (elementId == "_no_element_")
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to find element on page with selector '" + cssSelector + "'", "cssSelector");
        }
        return browser.ElementOfType<TElementType>(Find.ById(elementId));
    }
```